# TFS 2010 Windows Shell Extensions, how do I connect to a workspace?

Tags: tfs

I have VS 2010 and a TFS 2010 server set up and it's all working fine. I've checked out files to my local hard drive.

I installed the TFS Power Tools to be able to get to TFS through context menu in Windows. If I right click in a TFS project on my hard drive I get all the icons and it works.

My question is that how do I get the TFS menu if I have no source code from TFS on my hard drive?

Regards,
Magnus

Answer (score 4):

> "how do I get the TFS menu if I have
>   no source code from TFS on my hard
>   drive?"

First, you need to define a workspace and map server (source control) paths to local directories. You can do this in either of two ways:

- Use the [tf workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se.aspx) command to define a new workspace.
- Use Source Control Explorer to [Create a Workspace and Get Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384.aspx).

Once you've setup your workspace, you can right click any file or folder in your workspace you will find a Team Foundation Server option, expand it and you will see other version control options like checkout, check-in etc.